# Write a List<string> to an Excel.Range

Tags: c#, excel

I have the below excel Range:

```
workSheet.Range[workSheet.Cells[12, 2], workSheet.Cells[5000, 2]]
```

I have converted this excel range to a List and performed some data manipulations on the list.

```
object[,] cellValues = (object[,])inputRng.Value2;
List<string> lst = cellValues.Cast<object>().ToList().ConvertAll(x => Convert.ToString(x));
```

I want to assign the list back to the Excel Range.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Thanks for contributing. Can you show what you have already tried?

Comment: then convert the list back to a 2D array, or better work with a 2D array instead of converting to list.

Answer (score 3):

Here's some starting code for you that does what you want, it could probably be refined.

Your main "issue" is your conversion from the multidimensional array (`object[,] cellValues = (object[,])excelRange.Value;`) to the `List<string>` - if you could somehow keep this as a multidimensional array, then that would help your "setting" code - it depends what your other code is doing.

When you want to "set" your changes back, I've shown 2 ways to do it:

- either iterate through the cells (ranges) and set each value
- or provide a multi-dimensional array of values in advance and get the range to use them in one shot

Here:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

    namespace WindowsFormsApplication10
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                // Create starting spreadsheet

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet excelWorksheet;

            excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            excelApp.Visible = true;
            excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add();
            excelWorksheet = excelWorkbook.Sheets.Add();

            excelWorksheet.Activate();

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range excelRange = excelWorksheet.Range[excelWorksheet.Cells[12, 2], excelWorksheet.Cells[5000, 2]];

            // Turn off updating to make it faster

            excelApp.ScreenUpdating = false;

            // Set some initial data

            int i = 1;
            foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range cell in excelRange.Cells)
            {
                cell.Value = i;

                i++;
            }

            // Get the data from those cells as a list of strings

            object[,] cellValues = (object[,])excelRange.Value;
            List<string> lst = cellValues.Cast<object>().ToList().ConvertAll(x => Convert.ToString(x));

            // Modify the strings in some way

            for (int l = 0; l < lst.Count; l++)
            {
                lst[l] = lst[l] + "modified";
            }

            // Here are some different ways set the "cells" back

            // Set the cells back with the changes
            //------------------------------------

            // Option 1: using a multidimensional array

/* 
            object[,] cellValuesToWrite = new string[excelRange.Rows.Count, excelRange.Columns.Count];

            int z = 0;
            foreach (string str in lst)
            {
                cellValuesToWrite[z,0] = lst[z];
                z++;
            }

            excelRange.Value2 = cellValuesToWrite;
*/

            // Option 2: iterating the range of cells and "setting" the value

/*
            int z = 0;
            foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range cell in excelRange.Cells)
            {
                cell.Value = lst[z];
                z++;
            }

            excelRange.Value2 = lst;
*/

            // Turn updating back on

            excelApp.ScreenUpdating = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!!!  However your solution is using the for loop and setting the value for each cell, this one i thought of trying but dropped the idea because i have around 60000 rows to process in the excel range, which makes my system very slow, do we have any other approach to assign the List to excel range without iterating the each cell. The performance is important for my application.

Comment: if your excel "app" is onscreen, then using ScreenUpdating=false might speed it up. btw...your ConvertAll is a "loop" too.....you could also do a "Convert" back the other way to a list of Range for each cell....however, that would be equally as inefficient as iterating the excelRange sells methinks.

Comment: yes, i was looking for the option 1 that you provided, thanks a ton !!! now my app is faster using option 1. Thanks for the help.